# response.getWriter().print() send a jsonObjct to jsp,when the jsonobject has Long value,the jsp show the long value sometimes +1 or -1

Tags: java, json

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/dayMessage")
public void getDayRealTimeMessageList(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
JSONObject returnJson = new JSONObject();
 returnJson.put("value",111111111111);
 response.setContentType(Config.RESPONSE_TYPE_JAVASCRIPT);
 response.getWriter().print(returnJson);
}
```

The jsp show data like this :

```
{"value":111111111112}
```

The value always +1 or -1 ,this is a example but it really happened in my work. thank you again!

Comment: maybe the jsp is changing the value? can't determine the problem from the code above ...

Comment: when i open the explore console, see the http response Data,the value has be changed,so it‘s’ not jsp error... where i transfer long to String,it will be ok

Comment: can you share a minimal code, where this issue can be replicated

Comment: Try to put a String value to response for JSP.

Comment: this is chrome console data:



content: "新建事务15713892182658929"
createTime: "10-18 17:00:18"
customData: {transactionId: 15713892182658928, ciEntityId: 857}
fromUserId: "YAOLT"
fromUserName: "yaolt"
id: 108
isKeep: 0
isNew: 0



this is  database data, as "customData" value:

{"transactionId":15713892182658929,"ciEntityId":857}



i find when the last num is 9 ,it will be change to 8,and the last num is 5,it will be change to 4, the other num is ok.

Comment: the code is very simple, it just package database data as a JSONObject ,and send to jsp, there is one point was my wrong, the data not changed by jsp , it be changed during transmission

Answer (score 0):

A constant holding the maximum value an int can have, 2<sup>31</sup>-1. Don't you really get no error in your code here?

```
returnJson.put("value",111111111111);
```

Comment: thank you , this is real data : {"transactionId":15713892182658929,"ciEntityId":857}, 
  1111111111 just example,the code just package data to JSONObject and send to jsp,data be changed during transmission

Comment: Put your value as String. `returnJson.put("transactionId","15713892182658929");`